# Proof that $\pi =\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{4n}n!^4}{n(2n)!^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics, factorial, pi

In this post, the symbol $\sim$ means *asymptotically equivalent*.

The relationship between $\pi$ and factorials hinges on *Stirling's formula*:
$$n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\implies n!^2\sim 2\pi n\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{2n}.$$
In a similar manner,
$$(2n)!\sim \sqrt{4\pi n}\left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n}.$$
Then, by taking the ratio of the two quantities and simplifying one gets
$$\frac{(2n)!}{n!^2}\sim \frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi n}}.$$
By squaring both sides and further manipulation:
$$\pi =\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{4n}n!^4}{n(2n)!^2}.$$
Also, note that the last limit for $\pi$ above and
$$\frac{n!^2}{2n}\left(\frac{e}{n}\right)^{2n}$$
(which can be obtained as a limit for $\pi$ from *Stirling's formula* dircetly) have a different rate of convergence.

My question is, how can one justify the manipulations (e.g. squaring both sides) when the expressions are not equivalent but only asymptotically equivalent? When I used this I ran into problems:
$$\ln n!\sim n\ln n-n\, \text{(true)},$$
$$n!\sim e^{n\ln n-n}\, \text{(false)}.$$

Comment: This approach while correct can be viewed as circular if the proof of Stirling formula itself is based on limit in question. A typical proof is via the evaluation of integral $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^nx\,dx$.

Comment: Certainly it is not circular – since personally I used a proof of Stirling's formula from https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsApproximation.html, not Wallis integrals.

Comment: By the way, I think that Wallis integrals give $\pi =\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{4n+1}n!^4}{(2n+1)(2n)!^2}$ which is quite different from the limit in the question, as it approaches $\pi$ from below, not from above.

Comment: Well the limit in your previous comment is same as that in your question because if you divide those two expressions you get $\frac{2n}{2n+1}$ which tends to $1$.

Comment: Also to clarify, since you have used a different approach for Stirling this approach is not circular. I have already given my +1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right that not all operations with asymptotically equivalent expressions are correct. For example, $f\sim g$ doesn't necessarily imply $e^f\sim e^g$. However, $f\sim g$ implies $f^k\sim g^k$ where $k$ is an integer. This follows directly from properties of limits:
$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)^k}{g(x)^k}=\left(\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)^k=1^k=1 $$
(This can be generalized to $k\in\mathbb{R}$ provided $f(x)^k$ is defined). Since the only thing we're doing here is squaring, i.e. $k=2$, your manipulations are justified.

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid the $\sim$ by writing the Stirling formula in the form
$$n!=\sqrt{2\pi n}\left({n\over e}\right)^n\>g(n)\quad(n\geq1),\qquad \lim_{n\to\infty}g(n)=1\ ,$$
and similarly in the other equations, maybe with new $g$s.

Comment: But why is the approach with $\ln n!$ (as described in the question) flawed, then?

Comment: See the answer of bjorn93.

Answer (score 4):

The asymptotic equality $e^{f(n)} \sim e^{g(n)}$ means 
$$
\frac{{e^{f(n)} }}{{e^{g(n)} }}\to 1 \Leftrightarrow  e^{f(n) - g(n)}  \to 1 \Leftrightarrow f(n) - g(n) \to 0.
$$
But $f(n) \sim g(n)$ does not necessarily imply that the difference of the two sides tend to $0$ (or even that it is bounded). Thus $f(n) \sim g(n) \not\Rightarrow  e^{f(n)} \sim e^{g(n)}$. If, for example, $g(n)$ is evetually non-zero, then the reverse implication is true.

In your example
$$
\log n! - (n\log n - n) = \frac{1}{2}\log (2\pi n) + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right)
$$
which is not bounded.